# node.js what is User in passport.js

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm trying to make Node.js auth through steam API. I've installed passport-steam

```
passport.use(new SteamStrategy({
    returnURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/steam/return',
    realm: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    apiKey: 'your steam API key'
  },
  function(identifier, profile, done) {
    User.findByOpenID({ openId: identifier }, function (err, user) {
      return done(err, user);
    });
  }
));
```

What is User in function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User` here is a mongoose user model.

You can read about mongoose in the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com).  Mongoose is an ORM for a MongoDB database.

Passport in fact can use any store you would like and the `User` model there is just an example of how you can get the user and call `done` callback.